# Replace XML node with String in Perl using LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I'm currently using a perl script with LibXML to process a given XML file. This goes decently well, but if I have a node with both child nodes and free text, I begin to struggle.
An example input would be:

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        this node works fine
    </Error>
    <Error>
        some text <testTag>with a node</testTag> in between
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Expected output:

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        this node works fine
    </Error>
    <Error>
        some text HELLOwith a nodeHELLO in between
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

I tried replaceChild("HELLO", $testTagNode);  to replace the nodes with a string, which I could then (if needed) process further with a simple search-replace, but I only run into the "not a blessed reference" error. (I feel like that would have been pretty dirty if it actually worked that way.)

If I try to run a simple search-replace directly on the parent node like this

```
$error=~s/\</HELLO/g;
```

it will simply never trigger (no matter if I escape the < or not), because LibXML seems to ignore every tag that I don't specifically ask for; if I try to print out the second Error it will also give me just

```
some text with a node in between
```

which is actually a very nice functionality for the rest of the file, but not in this instance.

I can however do

```
$error->removeChild($testTagNode);
```

which shows me that it actually does get found, but doesn't help me further. I could theoretically remove the node, save the content, and then just insert the content back into the parent; the problem being that it needs to be at the exact location where it was before. The only thing that I could probably do is read in the entire file as a string, let the basic search-replace run over it BEFORE feeding it into LibXML, but that could create a pretty big overhead and isn't really a nice solution.

I feel like I'm overlooking something substantial, as this looks like a pretty basic tasks to do, but I can't seem to find anything. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong direction, and there is a completely different approach available. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to turn an XML Element into plain text in the first place? This feels like an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `testTag` element would remove all of its children too, so we must move the children of each `testTag` element into the parent of the `testTag` element before deleting the `testTag` element. In XML::LibXML, this is done as follows: (Tested)

```
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('/Errors/Error//testTag')) {
   my $parent = $node->parentNode();

   for my $child_node (
      XML::LibXML::Text->new("HELLO"),
      $node->childNodes(),
      XML::LibXML::Text->new("HELLO"),
   ) {
      $parent->insertBefore($child_node, $node);
   }

   $node->unbindNode();
}
```

---

Notes:

- Handles `testTag` elements with any number of text and element children.
- Handles `testTag` elements that aren't direct children of `Error` elements. Even handles nested `testTag` elements. (Use `/Errors/Error/testTag` instead of `/Errors/Error//testTag` if you only want to handle direct children of `Error` elements.)

Comment: Hmm, so effectively creating a new `#text` element wrapping that childnode? Neater than my approach.

Comment: @Sobrique, No. I don't wrap the children with a text node. That doesn't even make any sense since text nodes can't contain other nodes.

Comment: OK. I'll have to stare at it a little longer to figure out what's going on then.

Comment: @Sobrique, Removing the `testTag` element would remove all of its children too, so we gotta move the children out first. In array terms, we're doing `splice(@$parent, $idx_of_node, 1, "HELLO", @$node, "HELLO")`. The code moves the children of the `testTag` element to the `testTag` element's parent, positioning them just before the `testTag` element. Along with the children, the two requested text nodes are created there too. Finally, the now-empty `testTag` is removed.

Comment: The combination of LibXML::Text and insertBefore is exactly what I was looking for, and it works like a charm now. Beautiful little piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

In [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2) which is just a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), the following seems to work:

```
for //testTag/text() {
    insert text 'HELLO' prepend . ;
    insert text 'HELLO' append . ;
    move . replace .. ;
}
```

Translation back to XML::LibXML is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'm not sure it's acceptable to assume the childnres of `testTag` are only going to be text nodes.

Comment: Thanks for giving a different approach, but I will go with the ones that don't need more packages than I already have running.

Answer (score 1):

First off - I don't think what you're trying to do is necessarily particularly useful. However, I'll note - when you're processing your nodes - if you've got a nested node like in your second example, you actually get 3 'nodes' but two of which designated as `#PCDATA`.

So you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented_a' )->parse( \*DATA );
foreach my $error ( $twig->get_xpath('//Error') ) {
    my $replace_text;
    foreach my $child ( $error->children ) {
        my $tag = $child->tag;
        print "Child: $tag ", $child->trimmed_text, "\n";
        $tag = '' if $tag eq "#PCDATA";
        $replace_text .= $tag . $child->trimmed_text . $tag;
    }

    $error->set_text($replace_text);
    print $error ->trimmed_text, "\n";
}
print $twig->sprint;

__DATA__
<Errors>
    <Error>
        this node works fine
    </Error>
    <Error>
        some text <testTag>with a node</testTag> in between
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

This turns it into:

```
<Errors>
  <Error>this node works fine</Error>
  <Error>some texttestTagwith a nodetestTagin between</Error>
</Errors>
```

Obviously, you can then rename `testTag` to whatever you like.

(Bear with me - I'll have a look at how to do that in LibXML - unfortunately it doesn't install easily on my Windows box).

OK, so with `XML::LibXML`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;


my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );
foreach my $error ( $xml -> findnodes ( '//Error' ) ) {
   my $replace_text; 
   foreach my $child ( $error -> childNodes ) {
      my $tag = $child -> nodeName;
      $tag = '' if $tag eq '#text';
      $replace_text .= $tag . $child -> textContent . $tag; 
      $err -> removeChild($child);
   } 
   $err -> appendTextNode($replace); 
}

print $xml -> toString;

__DATA__
<Errors>
    <Error>
        this node works fine
    </Error>
    <Error>
        some text <testTag>with a node</testTag> in between
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's acceptable to assume the children of `testTag` are only going to be text nodes.

Comment: The LibXML solution does work, though there are 3 points which need to be corrected in your code: $err (twice) has to be $error, and in the last line, the $replace has to be $replace_text. (Just leaving this here for future onlookers.) Other than that, works fine. I will accept @ikegami's answer though, as his can deal with nested tags. Currently, your assumption with only text in the testTag nodes holds true, but maybe that changes, and being future-safe is always a good thing. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yeah, transcription error - LibXML doesn't install nicely on my Windows box.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
$error='<Errors>
<Error>
    this node works fine
</Error>
<Error>
    some text <testTag>with a node</testTag> in between
</Error>
</Errors>';

$error=~ s/<testTag>/HELLO/gs;
$error=~ s/<\/testTag>/HELLO/gs;
```